# How to specify Suppress​Message​Attribute.​Check​Id for .NET Standard Class Library?

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I'm writing a .NET Standard 2.0 Class Library on VS2017. In the Error List, I got some messages like:

> IDE0018   Variable declaration can be inlined

I can supress the warning [via the context menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-suppress-warnings-by-using-the-menu-item):
[image]

It created a `GlobalSuppressions.cs` in my project:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE1006:Naming Styles", Justification = "<Pending>", Scope = "member", Target = "~M:SomeType.SomeMethod()~System.Int32")]
```

I want to suppress all message like `IDE1006` so I modified it to

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE1006:Naming Styles")]
```

Now I want to manually supress `IDE1008` and others, but I don't know what's the standard description for `IDE1008`.
`[assembly: SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE1008:???")]`

I can find some `CA1234` warning definitions in [Analyzing Application Quality by Using Code Analysis Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/analyzing-application-quality-by-using-code-analysis-tools).

So my question is: **where are the definitions of IDE messages like `IDE1234`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nathen Silver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47254913/788168) is probably the most useful one, but I wanted to answer the direct question:

> So my question is: **where are the definitions of IDE messages like IDE1234?**

It might not have been true earlier, but you can find the definitions of the IDE messages on MSDN (learn.microsoft.com). For the specific error message `IDE0008` that you saw:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0007-ide0008

The page includes everything you need to generate the attribute:

> **Rule ID**: IDE0007 and IDE0008
>
> **Title**: IDE0007: Use 'var' instead of explicit type
> IDE0008: Use explicit type instead of 'var'
>
> **Category**: Style

I've found that you can usually put the IDE number at the end (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0008) and you'll be linked to the right page.

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a list of definitions for the IDE messages, but you don't need the standard description for the style to suppress it.

You can just do this:

```
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE1008")]
```