# What is required to include in a SuppressMessage attribute?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some code that violates, say, [CA1051](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1051):

```cs
public class Logger {
    // Generates a warning "Do not declare visible instance fields".
    public Level LogLevel = Level.Warning;
}
```

I want to suppress this warning, since I'm breaking that rule deliberately. [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/suppress-warnings#use-the-suppressmessageattribute) to use the [SuppressMessage attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute) to do so:

```cs
[SuppressMessage("Design", "CA1051: Do not declare visible instance fields", Justification = "Clearest way of exposing this field.")]
public Level LogLevel = Level.Warning;
```

But [all the examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute?view=net-6.0#examples) imply that:

- I have to find the documentation for the error on MSDN.
- I have to look up the category.
- I have to look up the full name of the warning

Is there *any* simpler way of suppressing the error/warning?

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Comment: I am just curious what the reasoning is for breaking that rule.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify Suppress​Message​Attribute.​Check​Id for .NET Standard Class Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45873680/how-to-specify-suppressmessageattribute-checkid-for-net-standard-class-libr)

Comment: @Silvermind it's merely an example, but in this case we'd have to expose a getter/setter, which provides no particular benefit that we need. So it saves us 6 lines of boilerplate.

Comment: @gunr2171 the question overlaps, but the way that question is phrased makes it very difficult to find the answer to *this* question. The core question there is `where are the definitions of IDE messages like IDE1234?`, and the answer *happened* to be that you don't need the message. I could have answered the other question by linking to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0007-ide0008

Comment: @Silvermind: public fields in  structures is a very viable reason to break that rule.

Comment: @PoulBak I meant: Why a public field?

Comment: @Silvermind: I always use fields in structures and properties in classes (structures are 'primitive' classes, that don't need properties).

Comment: @PoulBak Debatable. You talk about properties like they are a burdain. I would argue that there is a specific use case for writable public fields, other than a use case that someone created by him/her self, like relying on some kind of reflection in a factory class that only searches for fields. The use case is just extremely rare. A different case is  public readonly fields, they are a valid solution where you cannot create a public constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a simpler way of suppressing errors/warnings like this!

```cs
// Minimal required:
[SuppressMessage("", "CA1051")]
public Level LogLevel = Level.Warning;

// What I recommend
[SuppressMessage("", "CA1051", Justification = "Clearest way of exposing this field")]
public Level LogLevel = Level.Warning;
```

It seems undocumented, but the ID is sufficient to suppress the message. I recommend adding a `Justification` since that helps other readers of the code understand why you chose to break the rule.

Also note that Visual Studio proper will help you generate these suppression attributes automatically. VS Code just doesn't seem to.

Comment: I arrived here because I was surprised that the category could be left empty and wanted to know if it was something about my set up. Crazy that that is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation.